# Hibernate - When use sqlQuery, face "data exception: invalid datetime format" issue

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate

My code looks like:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query countQuery = session.
                createSQLQuery(queryString);
        Long totalFilteredRecords = ((Number)countQuery.uniqueResult())
                .longValue();
```

The `queryString` is:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE
  to_char(LAST_UPDATED_DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')
BETWEEN
  '2015-11-13 11:40:03'
AND
  '2015-11-13 11:34:03'
```

`LAST_UPDATED_DATE` is `Date` type.

I run this SQL on SQLDeveloper and it works well, but failed when run via `Hibernate`:

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: SQL Error: -3407, SQLState: 22007
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: data exception: invalid datetime format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss
```

My database is Oracle.

Could anybody help clarify is there anything wrong?

Comment: @Siyual No, it's correct oracle format. `mm` is for months, `mi` - for minutes.

Comment: Can you make sure, that your date is in correct format? Try to log values of `LAST_UPDATED_DATE` somewhere. For example, in log table.

Comment: Also, try `hh24:mi:ss` instead of `hh:mi:ss`

Comment: Oh, wait! `LAST_UPDATED_DATE` is a column with date type? So write directly `LAST_UPDATED_DATE between ... and ...`

Comment: @Dmitry I replace date format string from lower case to upper case and it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, it is a little unexpected simple... Replace lower case date format string to upper case.

Change `queryString` to:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM SOME_TABLE
WHERE
  to_char(LAST_UPDATED_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
BETWEEN
  '2015-11-13 11:40:03'
AND
  '2015-11-13 11:34:03'
```

And it works.

Answer (score 1):

it's not need to cast the date value to string and compare it, you could also use parameter for the **hql** query:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(id) "+
     "FROM SOME_TABLE "+
     "WHERE "+
     "  LAST_UPDATED_DATE >= :startDate AND LAST_UPDATED_DATE <=:endDate";
q.setParameter("startDate",your_start_date,TemporalType.DATE);
q.setParameter("endDate",your_end_date,TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: This is good way! But due to some reason I'm not able to change the code. Thus the only way is to pass a pure SQL query...

Answer (score 1):

Typical constrain of a **DATE** column is as follows

```
 SELECT COUNT(id)
 FROM SOME_TABLE
 WHERE
    LAST_UPDATED_DATE  /* Column with DATE format */
 BETWEEN
   /* DATE literal using explicit formatting */
   to_date('2015-11-13 11:40:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
 AND
   to_date('2015-11-13 11:34:03', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Yes another good way, if replace `yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss` to upper case, then it will work.